# How to resolve "Cannot add or update a child row" in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

I have written a PHP script to interact with a MySQL database. It is fairly near to completion, but I am getting an error to do with foreign key constraints.

I have a self contained function which should complete a MySQL transaction:

```
function    doTransaction($dbConnection,$ticketId,$units,$totalToPass,$newTransId,  $moneyValue,$datetime,$paymentId){

$flag = true;

$query4 = "INSERT INTO ticketlines (ticket,line,units,price,taxid,attributes) VALUES(\"".$ticketId."\", 0,".$units.",".abs($totalToPass).",'000',0x3c3f786d6c2076657273696f6e3d22312e302220656e636f64696e673d225554462d3822207374616e64616c6f6e653d226e6f223f3e3c21444f43545950452070726f706572746965732053595354454d2022687474703a2f2f6a6176612e73756e2e636f6d2f6474642f70726f706572746965732e647464223e3c70726f706572746965733e3c636f6d6d656e743e756e6943656e7461206f504f533c2f636f6d6d656e743e3c656e747279206b65793d2270726f647563742e74617863617465676f72796964223e3030303c2f656e7472793e3c656e747279206b65793d2270726f647563742e6e616d65223e202d3530253c2f656e7472793e3c2f70726f706572746965733e)";
$query3 = "INSERT INTO tickets (id,tickettype,ticketid,person,status) VALUES(\"".$ticketId."\",0,".$newTransId.",1,0);";
$query2 = "INSERT INTO receipts (id,money,datenew,attributes) VALUES(\"".$ticketId."\",".$moneyValue.",".date ("Y-m-d H:i:s",  strtotime($datetime)).",0x3c3f786d6c2076657273696f6e3d5c22312e305c2220656e636f64696e673d5c225554462d385c22207374616e64616c6f6e653d5c226e6f5c223f3e3c21444f43545950452070726f706572746965732053595354454d205c22687474703a2f2f6a6176612e73756e2e636f6d2f6474642f70726f706572746965732e6474645c223ea3c70726f706572746965733e3c636f6d6d656e743e756e6943656e7461206f504f533c2f636f6d6d656e743e3c2f70726f706572746965733e);";
$query1 = "INSERT INTO payments (id,receipt,payment,total,returnmsg)  VALUES(\"".$paymentId."\",\"".$ticketId."\",'Administrator  Adjustment',".$totalToPass.",'OK');";
$result = mysqli_query($dbConnection, $query1);

if (!$result) {
    $flag = false;
    echo "Error details: " . mysqli_error($dbConnection) . ".";
}

$result = mysqli_query($dbConnection, $query2);

if (!$result) {
    $flag = false;
    echo "Error details: " . mysqli_error($dbConnection) . ".";
}

if ($flag) {
    mysqli_commit($dbConnection);
    echo "<p>Adjustment Made</p><script>alert('Adjustment was made     successfully!!!')</script>";
 } else {
    mysqli_rollback($dbConnection);
    echo "<p>Adjustment Failed</p><script>alert('Adjustment was    unsuccessful!!!')</script>";;
}

mysqli_close($dbConnection);
}
```

When run this code returns the following error:

```
Error details: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key   
constraint fails (`bricabrac`.`payments`, CONSTRAINT  
`PAYMENTS_FK_RECEIPT` FOREIGN KEY (`RECEIPT`) REFERENCES `receipts`
(`ID`)).Error details: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the  
manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
syntax to use near '2015-02-20  
00:00:00,0x3c3f786d6c2076657273696f6e3d5c22312e305c2220656e636f64696e' 
at line 1.
```

I believe there may be a slight syntax issue with inserting the datetime value in `$query2`, the bit I really don't follow is the foreign key issue. I had tried changing the order of the queries but with no success.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is simply that you do not have a single quote around the `attributes` data field, it may look like a number field but it must be a text field so it needs to be quoted.

Try this its easier to read without all the escaping of the doublequote.

```
$datenew = date ("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($datetime));
$query2 = "INSERT INTO receipts (id,money,datenew,attributes) 
             VALUES('$ticketId',
                    $moneyValue,
                    '$datenew',
                   '0x3c3f786d6c2076657273696f6e3d5c22312e305c2220656e636f64696e673d5c225554462d385c22207374616e64616c6f6e653d5c226e6f5c223f3e3c21444f43545950452070726f706572746965732053595354454d205c22687474703a2f2f6a6176612e73756e2e636f6d2f6474642f70726f706572746965732e6474645c223ea3c70726f706572746965733e3c636f6d6d656e743e756e6943656e7461206f504f533c2f636f6d6d656e743e3c2f70726f706572746965733e')";

$absTotPr = abs($totalToPass);
$query4 = "INSERT INTO ticketlines (ticket,line,units,price,taxid,attributes) 
            VALUES('$ticketId',
                    0,
                    $units,
                    $absTotPr,
                    '000',
                    '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')";
```

Comment: Yes tried that, no joy. I also removed the field since both attributes columns allow nulls. That returned:  Error details: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '2015-02-20 00:00:00)' at line 1

Comment: The field wasn't actually a number value. It is actually a string of xml data. THe version of the code posted in my question was the string converted to hex and pre-pended with a null after the initial xml string with quotes through an error.

Comment: Come to think of it the datenew field will also need quoting, and the price need calcing outside the querystring, see my edit. Sorry was only looking for the obvious initially